# mysql logging table change history

Tags: mysql, logging, history

I want to log the changes history of tables in a single table
Eg:
table a(col1,col2,col3)
table b(col1,col2)
table history(tablename,olddata,newdata,modifiedDate,modifiedBy)

if i execute an update statement, for eg
     update a set col1=2,col2=4,col3=5
then it should log on the history table as

```
 a|col1=1,col2=2,col3=3| col1=2,col2=4,col3=5|13/6/2012|username
```

Comment: What's your question? If you are implicitly asking "how do I do this", you shouldn't expect an answer. What you will get an answer to is "I tried this .... and this .... happened. What can I do to get this ... behavior?"

Comment: I don't think MySQL has out-of-the-box logging such as this. You will need to implement your own logging, possibly using MySQL Triggers: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/triggers.html